# Function works with double quotes but not with single quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, quotes

I'm developing a page using webforms and I have a problem with my aspx.cs page. I have a treeview with values, that are supposed to work as a filter for gridview (sqlServer database). I save checked nodes in a string and the code works fine with double quotes, but when i use single quotes (which i need), nothing happens when i run it.

This is the code i'm running. I'm using the ClientScript just to see the string I saved. Code below is not working, if I replace ' with ", it works but I can't use it for filtering sql table. I've tried with replace, tried using character break, putting two single quotes, nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string exp1 = string.Empty;
            foreach (TreeNode node in Source_TreeView.CheckedNodes)
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    if (exp1 != string.Empty)
                    {
                        exp1 += " OR ";
                    }
                    exp1 += "Source=" + "'" + node.Value + "'";
                }
            }
            if (exp1 != string.Empty)
            {
                exp1 = "(" + exp1;
                exp1 = exp1 + ")";
            }
            exp1 = exp1.Replace("'", "''");
            string exp2 = string.Empty;
            foreach (TreeNode node in Sink_TreeView.CheckedNodes)
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    if (exp2 != string.Empty)
                    {
                        exp2 += " OR ";
                    }
                    exp2 += "Sink=" + "'" + node.Value + "'"; 
                }
            }
            if (exp2 != string.Empty)
            {
                exp2 = "(" + exp2;
                exp2 = exp2 + ")";
            }
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + exp1 + exp2 + "');", true);
        }
```

Comment: `exp1 = exp1.Replace("'", "''");`  why you need this line of code?

Comment: This was just one of my desperate tries..i tried using double quotes and then replacing it with single, but didn't work. Here I was just trying if it works with two single quotes.

Comment: `it didn't work` what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work cause one of your string exp1 or exp2 contains a simple quote. So when you send your script using RegisterStartupScript, you may have a Javascript error. Check the console

Try using \"

```
string yourScript  = string.format("alert(\"{0} {1}\");", exp1, exp2)
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", yourScript, true);
```